# onhover of google chart legend, tooltip is coming behind the modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, css, charts, google-visualization

I am using google charts in Bootstrap Modal, and the legends have long names. When i am hovering on the legend, the tooltip(default) showing the full name of legend is coming behind the Bootstrap Modal.

[image: The full name of legend is coming behind bootstrap modal]

How to make it appear over the modal?

Answer (score 1):

Finally after working for 2 hours i concluded that there is a class which is responsible for styling the tooltip which comes on hover of legend. You can easily style the tooltip using `.charts-tooltip`

Settings which I used:

```
.charts-tooltip  {
  color: #f00;
  width:300px;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  z-index: 2147483647;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can style it with CSS, you can use [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) to manipulate what "level" it is displayed on

Comment: I am unable to see the z-index of tooltip, though i know the z-index of modal

Comment: Then set the z-index of the tooltip to one that's greater than that of the modal. I don't see what the confusion is

Comment: I don't know how to style(change z-index) the browser's default tooltip.